# Проверить подключение к интернету

Tags: android

Как при запуске Activity проверять подключение к интернету и если подключение отсутствует, то выводить сообщение?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi
import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.net.ConnectivityManager
import android.net.Network
import android.net.NetworkInfo
import android.net.NetworkRequest
import android.os.Build
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi

class ConnectionLiveData(val context: Context) : LiveData<Boolean>() {

    private var connectivityManager: ConnectivityManager = context.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager

    private lateinit var connectivityManagerCallback: ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback

    override fun onActive() {
        super.onActive()

        updateConnection()

        when {
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N -> {
                connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(getConnectivityManagerCallback())
            }
            Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP -> {
                lollipopNetworkAvailableRequest()
            }
            else -> {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    context.registerReceiver(
                        networkReceiver, 
                        IntentFilter("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onInactive() {
        super.onInactive()
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            connectivityManager.unregisterNetworkCallback(connectivityManagerCallback)
        } else {
            context.unregisterReceiver(networkReceiver)
        }
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    private fun lollipopNetworkAvailableRequest() {
        val builder = NetworkRequest.Builder()
            .addTransportType(android.net.NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
            .addTransportType(android.net.NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)

        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(builder.build(), getConnectivityManagerCallback())
    }

    private fun getConnectivityManagerCallback(): ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            connectivityManagerCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                override fun onAvailable(network: Network?) {
                    postValue(true)
                }

                override fun onLost(network: Network?) {
                    postValue(false)
                }
            }
            return connectivityManagerCallback
        } else {
            throw IllegalAccessError("Should not happened")
        }
    }

    private val networkReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            updateConnection()
        }
    }

    private fun updateConnection() {
        val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo? = connectivityManager.activeNetworkInfo
        postValue(activeNetwork?.isConnected == true)
    }
}
```

*Вызов:*

```
public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val connectionLiveData = ConnectionLiveData(this)
    connectionLiveData.observe(this, Observer { isConnected ->
        isConnected?.let {
            //что-то
        }
    })
}
```

---

> **Deprecated**
>
> ```
> import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
> import android.content.Context;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
> import android.net.NetworkInfo;
>
> public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
>
>     public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;
>
>     public ConnectivityReceiver() {
>         super();
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
>         NetworkInfo activeNetwork = ((ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
>         boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
>         if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
>     }
>
>     public static boolean isConnected() {
>         NetworkInfo activeNetwork = ((ConnectivityManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)).getActiveNetworkInfo();
>         return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
>     }
>
>
>     public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
>         void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> ### 2.
>
> ```
> import android.app.Application;
>
> public class MyApplication extends Application {
>
>     private static MyApplication mInstance;
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate() {
>         super.onCreate();
>         mInstance = this;
>     }
>
>     public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
>         return mInstance;
>     }
>
>     public void setConnectivityListener(ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener
> ```
>
> listener) {
>               ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
>           }
>       }
>
> ### 3.
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     package="...">
>
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
>
>     <application
>         android:name=".MyApplication"
>         ...>
>         ...
>
>         <receiver
>             android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver"
>             android:enabled="true">
>             <intent-filter>
>                 <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
>             </intent-filter>
>         </receiver>
>
>     </application>
>
> </manifest>
> ```
>
> ### 4.
>
> ```
> private void checkConnection() {
>     boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
>     showSnack(isConnected);
> }
>
>
> private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
>     String message;
>     if (isConnected) message = "Good! Connected to Internet";
>     else message = "Sorry! Not connected to internet";
>     Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.fab), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>     MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
> }
>
> @Override
> public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
>     showSnack(isConnected);
> }
> ```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51295/discussion-on-answer-by-ifr0z----).