# Не корректно отрабатывает метод onReceive()

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

Имеется BroadcastReceiver, который должен отработать, если будет утеряно подключение к WiFi.
Как должно быть:

Приложение работает - WiFi выключили - отрабатывает onReceive() - выполнение процессов прекращается и пользователь об этом уведомляется.

Вместе с реагированием на отключение WiFi метод onReceive() отрабатывает и в таком сценарии:
Приложение запустили с выключенным WiFi - включили WiFi - метод onReceive() тоже отрабатывает. Т.е, получается, что WiFi включен, а пользователь видит сообщение об обратном. 
Как это пофиксить? .

```
    public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
           if (!(ni != null && ni.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)) {
                context.stopService(new Intent(context, NotificationService.class));
                Intent ss = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                ss.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                ss.putExtra("noWifi", "noWifi");
                context.startActivity(ss);
            }
        }
    }
```

Манифест:

```
<receiver android:name=".WifiReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="100">
                <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/606179/205563

Comment: Дело в том, что wi-fi подключается не за долю секунды, я сам только что протестировал. Т.е. как только нажали на wi-fi он сначала все равно скажет что интернет не подключен, но как только wi-fi почует обмен данными, то вуаля инет подключен

Comment: Да и для того, чтобы проверить эту ситуацию визуально TYPE_WIFI не достаточно, добавь еще TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED и сразу все встанет на свои места

Comment: @iFr0z спасибо. Но как тогда быть в моём случае? Делать задержку в 5-10 секунд, что бы дать WiFi приконнектится - разумное решение?

Comment: Не поверите, я сам сейчас над этим парюсь :DDD задержка очень кастыльное решение т.к. устройства разные бывают и их мощность к сожалению тож :( т.е. хрен подгадаешь скок секунд нужно...

Comment: хлопцы, если мне не изменяет память, то TYPE_CONNECT_OR_CONNECTED

Comment: или это поможет https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState.html, хотя может и этот флаг подойти WIFI_STATE_ENABLED.

Comment: @A-Z первым в момент переключения WiFi отрабатывает OBTAINING_IPADDR и дальше считывание состояния не идёт.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел лучшее [решение](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/). **Вся прелесть в isConnectedOrConnecting(); -**  он работает как надо вообще! Т.е. проблема "*Дело в том, что wi-fi подключается не за долю секунды, я сам только что протестировал. Т.е. как только нажали на wi-fi он сначала все равно скажет что интернет не подключен, но как только wi-fi почует обмен данными, то вуаля инет подключен*" **- решилась**. И не нужно делать задержку искусственную.

### 1.

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectivityReceiver
        extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;

    public ConnectivityReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
            connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(isConnected);
        }
    }

    public static boolean isConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager
                cm = (ConnectivityManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetwork != null
                && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }


    public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
        void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
    }
}
```

### 2.

```
import android.app.Application;

public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static MyApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static synchronized MyApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void setConnectivityListener(ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
        ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
    }
}
```

### 3.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="info.androidhive.checkinternet">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        ...>
        ...

        <receiver
            android:name=".ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

### 4.

```
private void checkConnection() {
    boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();
    showSnack(isConnected);
}


private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
    String message;
    int color;
    if (isConnected) {
        message = "Good! Connected to Internet";
        color = Color.WHITE;
    } else {
        message = "Sorry! Not connected to internet";
        color = Color.RED;
    }

    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
            .make(findViewById(R.id.fab), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);

    View sbView = snackbar.getView();
    TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    textView.setTextColor(color);
    snackbar.show();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
    showSnack(isConnected);
}
```

P.s. в ссылке видео, где наглядно можно увидеть как идеально работает.

Comment: Шикарно! Работает как надо. Спасибо)

Comment: @Haze рад был помочь!) не забудь отметить галочкой ответ:)

Comment: я бы с радостью, но "Спасибо за ваш отзыв! Ваши голоса начнут влиять на рейтинг сообщений, как только ваша репутация превысит порог в 15 баллов"

Comment: @Haze аааа, точно)

Comment: Ну, именно это я и имел в виду, просто не помнил метод это или флаг.